# LP作成の効率的な方法が分からない

Tags: css

LPの制作方法がもっと効率的にならないか迷走し始めたため質問いたしました。

■前提
私は現在LPを基本的なコーディングで作成しております。
そのためコーディングのみでLP作成をする際に、
何か別の方法（ツール）を使ったほうが効率的ではないかと考えました。

一例で恐縮ですが、今回の質問では下記のLPを作成した場合でご回答お願いいたします。
https://service.ourly.jp/

■私の認識
デザインは自由に調整したいので、「コーディング×〇〇」みたいな合せ技みたいな方法が伺えたら嬉しい限りです！
ペライチ等のノーコードツールを用いての作成が効率的とは思ったのですが、CSSでいじれる範囲が制限されているので、結局コーディングのほうが効率的なのでは…とも思いました。

■お聞きしたいこと
「ペライチでベースを作って、CSSでデザイン調整」など、皆さんがLP作成をされる際にやりやすい方法等を教えていただけますと幸いです、

初歩的な質問となり大変恐縮ですが、ご回答いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: コーディングだけではなくてそもそも「ペライチ作成」についても重要な要素だったりするのですが、そのあたりも回答に含めてもいいですか？それとも本当にコーディングの部分だけの回答を求めていますか？

Comment: SEO に特化した話というわけでも無さそうなので、ランディングページのように対象を絞るよりは単に "web サイト (ページ)" 位の表現でも十分な気がします。

Comment: keitaro_so様
ペライチ作成の要素も含めてご回答いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: cubick様
添削もありがとうございます。
そうですね…Webページ1枚という表現のほうが幅広く回答いただけそうですね。